# Character bone not following constraint

Tags: bones

my character is not following a limit of rotation. see

[image]

[image]

In the image i have a rotation constraint. its not working.

EDIT

I kind of got it working, but after adding the pole target, the knee doesnt bend.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your statements and have a clear question.  Its seems your progress is changing rapidly.  Perhaps your original question is no longer valid and can be deleted/modified.  What do you want to achieve? What is failing? What is succeeding? Your first image can be improved/deleted since the settings are covered up by context help tool tip.